# ggplot custom formatting error

Tags: r, ggplot2, customization, legend

I am working with a large database (tens of thousands) of points for a suite of climate variables that I want to plot in a scatterplot and group by Forest.type. I also have a set of sites (site1-7) that I want to plot on the same graph. Sites1-7 are just single points that each represent a different factor level within Forest.type, whereas the other levels each have thousands of points.

The problem I'm having is that when I graph the points, Sites1-7 are graphed incorrectly (i.e. the points don't correspond to the data) or alternatively, I'm formatting the graph incorrectly. I've spent a lot of time trying to find my error, and modifying the below graphing code in different ways, but haven't been able to do so.

A subset of my data (combo.df3) is below.

```
            CID Forest.type    PptAnn   TmaxAnn
1      61228534       site1  62744.88  783.0098
2      61228535       site2  79771.21  800.0628
3      61228536       site3 129822.54  831.5902
4      61228537       site4 130943.42  683.3425
5      61228538       site5  96531.09  902.3692
6      61228539       site6  98594.19  973.1728
7      61228540       site7  91160.96 1044.0000
11000       778        pipo  41832.00 1382.0000
21000      3269        pipo  41829.00 1074.0000
31000      3427        pipo  45357.00 1119.0000
993     1664171        pipo  41739.00 1309.0000
1993    3877208        pipo  56711.00 1103.0000
2993    6076595        pipo  46701.00 1166.0000
3993    7964984        pipo  72754.00 1417.0000
4993   10118766        pipo  61969.00 1083.0000
40993  12452128       dryMC  91025.00  835.0000
41993  24625242       dryMC  62317.00 1176.0000
42993  37503245       dryMC  52043.00  903.0000
43993  49283896       dryMC  40195.00 1124.0000
44993  61171523       dryMC  61583.00  987.0000
80993   8887400     moistMC 116187.00  975.0000
81993  17990513     moistMC  81670.00 1091.0000
82993  27239046     moistMC  83496.00 1316.0000
83993  36961854     moistMC  72694.00 1502.0000
84993  45104630     moistMC  66103.00 1038.0000
120993   253336        cold  40416.00 1065.0000
121993   697374        cold  64542.00  797.0000
122993  1007005        cold  55362.00  793.0000
123993  1467764        cold  72555.00 1407.0000
124993  1759938        cold  66139.00  741.0000
160993   434320       aspen  33372.00 1239.0000
161993   999534       aspen  52696.00  922.0000
162993  1953326       aspen  84496.00 1059.0000
163993  3548225       aspen  87807.00  653.0000
164993  4941243       aspen  60323.00 1001.0000
```

My graphing code is below:

```
ggplot(data=combo.df3, aes(x=PptAnn/1000, y=TmaxAnn/100, group=rev(Forest.type), size=rev(Forest.type))) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=rev(Forest.type))) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(rep(1, times=7), rep(0.5, times=5)), guide="none") + 
  scale_size_manual(values=rev(c(rep(5, times=7), rep(1, times=5))), guide="none") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = rev(c('black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'gold1', 'red3', 'green4', 'darkblue', 'olivedrab3')), guide="none") + 
  xlab("Annual Precipitation (cm)") + ylab(expression(paste("Annual Tmax ( ",degree,"C", ")"))) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5), title=NULL)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size=rel(2)), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size=rel(2)), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",colour="black", size=rel(2), vjust=-.5), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",colour="black", size=rel(2)), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=rel(1.5)), legend.title = element_text(size=rel(1.5)),
        legend.position = c(0.85, 0.7), legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="white", colour="black"), plot.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank())
```

This code produces the following graphic.

[image]

If you look closely, the large black dots do not correspond to the data from sites1-7, as I intend.

I may have errors unrelated to this problem in the code, which I haven't dealt with yet. Any ideas on where I've gone wrong on the plotting/formatting that is causing this error?

I also tried graphing this by separating sites1-7 into a separate dataframe and adding an extra geom_point argument to graph and format these plots. This graphed all points correctly, but then I had problems understanding how to format legends from two separate datasets on the same graph. It seemed the best solution was to have all data in one dataframe.

Comment: Why all these `rev`s? Get rid off those and it should work.

Comment: I included them initially to plot in a desired order so that the black points showed more clearly than others when thousands of points are plotted. If I remove the revs, it appears the points do plot correctly, but if I plot the entire dataset the black dots are mostly hidden by the other. I guess the best solution to control plotting order is not to use rev, but to change the order of the factor levels. Is that right?